# Android - Firebase string returns 'null'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay,

I think this is really strange.
I've had an Android Studio project with an open Firebase database (read/write: "true"), and there I managed to write and retrieve data.

Now I've started a new project, got it synced with my Android Studio and downloaded the 'google-service.json'. Same thing as before.

Now my Android project is able to write data but isn't able to retrieve data. Strange!
I've searched the web, getting mostly redirected to StackOverflow and tried it all. It's just not difficult at all, but I don't know where it's going wrong.

- My gradle's got:

  ```
  repositories {
      maven {
          url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
  }
  ```

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'

- My project is synced: I've followed the steps 'Tools' > 'Firebase' > 'Realtime Database';
- Android Studio is logged in with the correct account;
- I've downloaded the 'google-service.json' and put it in the right place;
- My Firebase has the following format:

> **currentVersion**: "2.06"

Nothing special you'ld think.

- Got this code:

  ```
  FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("currentVersion");

  databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          // This method is called once with the initial value and again
          // whenever data at this location is updated.
          versionCheckFirebase = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
          // Failed to read value
      }
  });

  Toast.makeText(this, versionCheckFirebase, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  ```

Without any problem I can write data to this database, via:

> databaseReference.setValue("2.06");

But when I read this value from the database, it's an empty String (null).

**How? Why?**

**-- edit --**
*Update after suggestion of @Bob Snyder*

```
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("currentVersion");
    //databaseReference.setValue("2.06");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            versionCheckFirebase = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, versionCheckFirebase, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
        }
    });
```

This still shows an empty toast message.
But when I update the data in Firebase, it directly shows the data in a toast.

What I want is:
- When I call this method, it should get the data at this time and do something with it. But now the data only gets called/updated/retrieved whenever I update the Firebase database.

**-- edit --** *Update after suggestion of @Bob Snyder*

**SOLUTION**

Got it working:

```
public void getCurrentVersionFirebase(){
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("currentVersion");
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            String dataFromFirebase = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            checkAppForUpdate(dataFromFirebase);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
        }
    });
}
```

And:

```
public void checkAppForUpdate(String dataFromFirebase){
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Do you have permissions in Firebase realtime database? Does it work on another strings?

Comment: I see it's working, whenever I update the database, but I want to fetch/retrieve the data only once, whenever I call the method to retrieve the data and do something with it's data.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener()`.

Comment: "now the data only gets called/updated/retrieved whenever I update the Firebase database" That is not how Firebase's `ValueEventListener ` works. When you attach a listener Firebase immediately starts reading the value at the location and fires `onDataChange()` with the value it fins.

Comment: That seems to work, but the data retrieval is very slow and methods later on, using this value, display null. The toast in the dataretrieval is the value I want it to be. But I make sure the next method, which uses the data, is activated right after the data retrieval. I'll update my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onDataChange()` callback is asynchronous.  In your current code, the callback will not have run when your statement to show the toast executes.  Move your toast into that method:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
    // whenever data at this location is updated.
    versionCheckFirebase = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    Toast.makeText(this, versionCheckFirebase, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Still isn't working. See edit in top post for more info on this.